# regular expression find a white-space character and non-white-space character

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

Help me fix my regular expression::

```
(REGEXP_SUBSTR(WORD, '#time\S[0-9]{1,2}'  )) as reg
```

I want to get the result:

```
'#time 52' 
'#time20'
```

If I write: `(REGEXP_SUBSTR(WORD, '#time\S[0-9]{1,2}'  ))` as reg

result: #time20

If I write: `(REGEXP_SUBSTR(WORD, '#time\s[0-9]{1,2}'  ))` as reg

result: #time 52

SQL query:

```
SELECT
(REGEXP_SUBSTR(WORD, '#time\S[0-9]{1,2}'  )) as reg
FROM(
select
'text #time 52 texttexttext  #time20 text'  as WORD
from dual
)tabl
```

How can I fix it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the **requirement** in this question? Not the **desired result**, but the logic that leads to that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is the expression you want:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(WORD, '#time\s*[0-9]{1,2}')
```

This will handle any number of spaces (including 0) between "#time" and the digits.  If you want at most one, use `?` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the exact substring `#text` followed by an *optional* space and then one or two digits? Then `'#text\s?\d{1,2}'` will work. `?` means optional.

Your `'#text\S\d{1,2}'` is incorrect in that case; it allows **and requires** a non-space character between `#text` and one or two digits. In your example it just happens to match the first digit and then `\d{1,2}` matches the second digit, but that is only a coincidence. It would also match `#text+00` and `#text123`. But it will **not** match `#text4` (if not followed by one or two more digits).